# python member str performance too slow

Tags: python, string, performance

I have encountered a strange performance problem when adding to an str class member in python 2.7.3. I know that accessing local variables are faster, however, in the problem below, there is more than 100x speed difference between the two loops. The one that accesses a.accum_ starts fast but slows down, as if str **iadd** is O(n^2) with the length of str.

Does anyone know the reason?

```
# Fast ( < 1sec):
accum = str()
for ii in range(1000000):
    if (ii % 10000) == 0:
        print 'fast cnt', ii
    accum += 'zzzzz\n'

# Much slower ( > 5 mins):
class Foo:
    pass
a = Foo()
a.accum_ = str()
for ii in range(1000000):
    if (ii % 10000) == 0:
        print 'slow cnt', ii
    a.accum_ += 'zzzzz\n'
```

Comment: It is surely because in the first approach is first approach the string will have only one reference during its lifetime and CPython can optimise this case, hence O(N) time. In second case the reference count surely increased from 1(but where exactly?), hence the quadratic time.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Reference count is the same in both cases, but as the answer points out, there is a specific optimization against the first case, but not against the second, and that's why the second case requires quadratic time.

Comment: @doublep I am not sure how you're trying to count the references, but check the refcount before `+=` and **during** `+=`. It should increase by atleast  1.

Answer (score 6):

For the first example it is pretty clear that it is case of single reference optimisation(there are two references actually: one from the object itself and one [`LOAD_FAST`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_FAST); [`unicode_concatenate`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/ceval.c#L5201) will try to reduce it to 1 before passing control to [`PyUnicode_Append`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L11027)) done by CPython using this [`unicode_modifiable`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L1620) function:

```
static int
unicode_modifiable(PyObject *unicode)
{
    assert(_PyUnicode_CHECK(unicode));
    if (Py_REFCNT(unicode) != 1)
        return 0;
    if (_PyUnicode_HASH(unicode) != -1)
        return 0;
    if (PyUnicode_CHECK_INTERNED(unicode))
        return 0;
    if (!PyUnicode_CheckExact(unicode))
        return 0;
#ifdef Py_DEBUG
    /* singleton refcount is greater than 1 */
    assert(!unicode_is_singleton(unicode));
#endif
    return 1;
}
```

But in the second case as the instance data is stored in a Python `dict` rather than a simple variable, so the things get little different.

```
a.accum_ += 'foo'
```

actually requires prefetching the value of `a.accum_` and storing it on to the stack. So, now the string has **atleast three** references: one from the instance dictionary, one from [`DUP_TOP`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/dis.html#opcode-DUP_TOP) and one from [`PyObject_GetAttr`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_GetAttr) used by [`LOAD_ATTR`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_ATTR). Hence, Python cannot optimise this case as modifying one of them in-place will affect other references as well.

```
>>> class A:
    pass
...
>>> a = A()
>>> def func():
    a.str = 'spam'
    print a.str
    return '_from_func'
...
>>> a.str = 'foo'
>>> a.str += func()
spam
```

You would expect the output here to be `'spam_from_func'`, but it is going to be different because the original value of `a.str` was stored by Python before `func()` was called.

```
>>> a.str
'foo_from_func'
```

Byte Code:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def func_class():
        a = Foo()
        a.accum = ''
        a.accum += 'zzzzz\n'
...
>>> dis.dis(func_class)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (Foo)
              3 CALL_FUNCTION            0 (0 positional, 0 keyword pair)
              6 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  3           9 LOAD_CONST               1 ('')
             12 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             15 STORE_ATTR               1 (accum)

  4          18 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             21 DUP_TOP
             22 LOAD_ATTR                1 (accum)
             25 LOAD_CONST               2 ('zzzzz\n')
             28 INPLACE_ADD
             29 ROT_TWO
             30 STORE_ATTR               1 (accum)
             33 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             36 RETURN_VALUE
```

---

Note that this optimisation was done in [around 2004](http://bugs.python.org/issue980695)(CPython 2.4) to prevent users from 
slowness of `a += b` or `a = a + b`, so it is mostly meant for simple variables and works only if the next instruction is `STORE_FAST`(local variable), `STORE_DEREF`(closures) and `STORE_NAME`. It is not a general solution, [the best way to do this in Python is to create a list and join its items using `str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange).

> **CPython implementation detail**: If `s` and `t` are both strings, some Python implementations such as CPython can usually perform an in-place
>   optimization for assignments of the form `s = s + t` or `s += t`. When
>   applicable, this optimization makes quadratic run-time much less
>   likely. This optimization is both version and implementation
>   dependent. For performance sensitive code, it is preferable to use the
>   `str.join()` method which assures consistent linear concatenation
>   performance across versions and implementations.

Answer (score 2):

Python strings are immutable and so *can't* have an `__iadd__` method. What you are witnessing in the first example is a micro optimisation of the CPython interpreter. In the first example the interpreter has noticed that it has a local variable that has a reference count of 1. Thus, the interpreter can cheekily get away with modifying the string in place. Even though this violates the contract of `str`, at no point during the execution of the program will it be apparent that this contract was briefly violated.

In the latter example this micro optimisation isn't being implemented, which is why it's so slow. It looks like the optimisation could be applied, so I'm not sure why it isn't being applied.

Generally though, if building a string, collate the substrings in a list and then use `str.join` to create the end product.

Comment: The relevant optimization is in `string_concatenate()` in file `ceval.c`. Obviously, this is relevant to CPython.